# How to make this script loop until there are no errors python?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to make this script loop until there are no errors but I'm pretty new to python and just keep encountering errors

I've tried everything I know but this isnt an easy task for me

```py
  def change_screen_name(self):
       print("Attempting change...")
       try:
           status = self.api.update_profile(screen_name="name")
           print("Name updated!")
       except tweepy.TweepError as error:
           resp = error.response.json()["errors"][0]
           print("Name unavailable.")
           print("{} ({})".format(resp["message"], resp["code"]))
       finally:
           return self
```

Expected result is to continue attempting the same namechange until there are no errors but it currently only tries once then stops

Comment: What errors? Please be more precise

Comment: `finally` executes whether it works in the try or has an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
def change_screen_name(self):
    while True:
        print("Attempting change...")
        try:
            status = self.api.update_profile(screen_name="name")
            print("Name updated!")
            return self
        except tweepy.TweepError as error:
            resp = error.response.json()["errors"][0]
            print("Name unavailable.")
            print("{} ({})".format(resp["message"], resp["code"]))
```

1) Have an infinite loop running

2) Break out the infinite loop once your attempt succeeds.

3) Finally runs after try/except. If you have a finally statement it will always run.